# How do I make a wheel to rotate around its own axis instead of around its parent object?

Tags: drivers

I added a driver for the x axis rotation and set up the driver editor it's rotation is around the parent object I want it to be around its own axis I tried filling with the degree values in the rotation box but to no avail.

Comment: More information would be very helpful here. Perhaps you could upload a screen shot or two, and upload a copy of your ~.blend file to Blend-exchange.giantcowfilms, and edit a link to the file into your question.

Comment: Simply I. Want to a wheel to rotate around its own axis I can't add a screenshot now

Comment: A quick search of Youtube revealed a number of different tutorials about using drivers to animate wheels. Which have you viewed?

Comment: Have you checked that your object's axes and origin point are correct? Without a .blend or even screen shots it's hard to imagine what went wrong where, but that's the first question I have to ask.

Comment: I have looked at @brasshat YouTube videos b4 I posted this question and expected similar results as to the video with the rigging for the car wheels I'm typing this on my mobile so can't post a screenshot until later

Comment: A vertex parent may do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because the origin point of the wheel is in the wrong place.

Select the wheel in Object mode
go into the (T) panel->Tools->Edit->Set Origin to Center